# Некорректно работает отладчик gdb c std::vector, std::map

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, gdb

Некорректно работает отладчик c std::vector, std::map
Используется VS 2019. При отладке, если в наблюдение добавить вызов метода size у конкретного объекта vector или map и начать двигаться по шагам - приложение падает.

В вычисляемых значениях по методу size лежит мусор. Если выводить в консоль значения, возвращаемые методом size, то там корректные значения.

gcc (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.1.0

GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3

**Update**

Пример кода:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> vect;
printf("%u\n", static_cast<uint32_t>(vect.size())); // в консоль корректно выводится 0
printf("add step\n"); // breakpoint
printf("add step2\n"); // при переходе сюда падаем
```

**Update 2**

Последние 3 записи стека вызовов:

```
lib_server_lib.dll!std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::size(const std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > * const this) Line 916 C++ // здесь fault
<function called from gdb>  
lib_server_lib.dll!Test::Test(Test * const this) Line 10    C++ // здесь breakpoint
```

Comment: покажите код. без отладчика работает? пробовали заменитьт отладчик на вывод в консоль?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, обновил вопрос примером кода, в консоль, как писал ранее, выводится все норм, или вы что-то другое имели ввиду?

Comment: vs и gcc/gdb  одном флаконе? что то интересное.

Comment: да, имел в виду вывод принтфом (или подобным), чтобы исключить, что у вас там невалидный код) а как у вас настроена отладка и почему стоит метка visual studio, имеется в виду visual studio code редактор или полноценная visual studio?

Comment: установлена ли опция -g для gcc ?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, результат такой же что и с ключом -g и с -ggdb, используется именно visual studio.
Конфигурация для запуска отладчика:
{
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "name": "server-Debug(x32)",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "program": "${debugInfo.target}",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "c:\\msys64\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "externalConsole": true
    },

Comment: приведенный конфиг говорит об использовании vs code)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, используется сборщик CMake (тип проекта в VS CMake), я не знаю как в этом случае именно в VS настроить отладчик, поэтому конфигурирую через конфигурационные файлы, такие как как в vs code, но все это крутится именно в vs.

Comment: я слабо понимаю, как это настроено, поэтому какого-то осмысленного ответа дать не могу... если проект под винду, то почему бы не компилить и дебажить студией?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, разработка идет в windows, проект работает в linux.

Comment: Есть подозрение. что в полном коде есть UB, а size отпработал правильно, потому что оптимизировало. Нужен более полный код.

Comment: @KoVadim, что такое UB? Обновил вопрос, добавив стек вызовов

Comment: UB = неопределенное поведение (undefined behavior).

Comment: @cassius куска стека вряд ли поможет

Comment: хотя... если это dll, и вектор "пролетает" через границу exe-dll, то все начинает сходиться

Comment: @KoVadim, dll используется при юнит тесте проекта; попробовал отладить непосредственно exe-шник, в отладчике size() показывает мусор, но падает не сразу, а раза с 3-го

Comment: Если там мусор, то оно не обязано сразу же падать. Может и через 10 раз упасть.